# Why is $\sum_{i=0}^N S_i^z S_{i+1}^z |\uparrow ... \downarrow_n ... \uparrow \rangle = \frac{1}{4}(N-4)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, spin-models, spin-chains

I am following these (http://edu.itp.phys.ethz.ch/fs13/int/SpinChains.pdf) lecture notes and I can't understand why given the following XXX Heisenberg hamiltonian
$$
\mathcal{H}=\frac{J N}{4}-J \sum_{i} \left(\frac{1}{2}\left(S_{i}^{+} S_{i+1}^{-}+S_{i}^{-} S_{i+1}^{+}\right)+S_{i}^{z} S_{i+1}^{z}\right),
$$
then,
$$
\mathcal{H}\left|\ldots \downarrow_{n} \ldots\right\rangle=-J\left(\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\left|\ldots \downarrow_{n-1} \ldots\right\rangle}_\text{I understand}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}\left|\ldots \downarrow_{n+1} \ldots\right\rangle}_\text{I understand}-\underbrace{\left|\ldots \downarrow_{n} \ldots\right\rangle}_\text{I don't understand}\right).
$$
I don't understand the third term in the RHS because it implies
$$
J\sum_i S_{i}^{z} S_{i+1}^{z} \left|\ldots \downarrow_{n} \ldots\right\rangle = \frac{J}{4}(N-4)
$$
instead of
$$
J\sum_i S_{i}^{z} S_{i+1}^{z} \left|\ldots \downarrow_{n} \ldots\right\rangle = \frac{J}{4}(N-2). \quad (*)
$$
Shouldnt $(*)$ be correct? For every $S_{i}^{z} S_{i+1}^{z}$ you get a factor of $\frac{1}{4}$, there would be $N$ of those factors wouldn't it be for the lonely downspin at position $n$ which gets counted twice (once by $S_{i}^{z}$ and another by  $S_{i+1}^{z}$) thus $\frac{1}{4}(N-2)$.

Of course, with my reasoning I get the wrong result so... why am I wrong?

Comment: As pointed out by @QuantumApple, it is easy to see if you draw all the factors like         $$\overbrace{\underbrace{\frac{1}{4}+ ... +  \frac{1}{4}}_{n-1} - \underbrace{\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{4}}_2 + \underbrace{\frac{1}{4} + ... + \frac{1}{4}}_{N-(n-1)-2}}^N$$ and then collect them $\frac{1}{4}(n-1+N-n+1-2)-\frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{4}(N-2)-\frac{2}{4}= \frac{1}{2}(N-4)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spin at position $n$ does get counted twice but it changes the value of $S_i^z S_{i+1}^z$ from $+\frac{1}{4}$ to $-\frac{1}{4}$, that's a change of $-\frac{1}{2}$. Multiply by $2$ because two elements of the sum get changed and you get your answer.

Comment: I feel so stupid... thanks!